# SimpleXML extract TEXT of ID child

Tags: php, simplexml, telegram-bot

I need the text of the of the  of this xml file to use it in telegram, if the xml cames without "id" and "name" i can do it, but no with the tags

```html
<root>
<origen>...</origen>
<trend>
    <zone id="809" name="AGi">
      <subzone id="809" name="AGi">
        <text>
          I want this text.
        </text>
      </subzone>
    </zone>
</trend>
```

```
function getIdTEXT($chatId){
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' =>  array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
    $url = "http://www.thexmlfile/MM.xml";

    $xmlstring = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $info = "information: ".$array['trend']['zona id="809" nama="AGi"']['subzone id="809" nombre="AGi"']['text'];

    sendMessage($chatId, $info);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to output `$array` and see it's structure?

Comment: Try [using SimpleXML as intended](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) rather than using that weird `json_decode(json_encode())` hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XPath` to query the exact node you want :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$nodes = $xml->xpath("/root/trend/zone[@id = 809 and @name= 'AGi']/subzone[@id = 809 and @name = 'AGi']/text") ;
$text = (string)$nodes[0] ;
echo $text ; // I want this text.
```

Comment: What's `strip_tags` doing in there? `(string)$nodes[0]` will give you the text content you want, there are no tags to strip. Also, you don't need `LIBXML_NOCDATA`, just `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);` will do fine.

Comment: @IMSoP is correct, strip_tags is not necessary. Here's a demo of the code working: https://3v4l.org/ZUugY

Comment: I think you've correctly read between the lines of OPs question and this is the right way to get the result they want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert your SimpleXML object to an array to access values from it, you can just access them like object variables:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo $xml->trend->zone->subzone->text;
```

Output:

```
I want this text.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/O16O1)

Comment: She gives me error T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM 

$info= $xml->trend->zone->subzone->text;

Comment: You don't need `LIBXML_NOCDATA` either, but otherwise this is spot on.

Comment: @ILB That error is a reference to an unexpected `::` in your code; since there is no `::` in the code in this answer, that error has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: @IMSoP the load line was copied from OPs code, hence the `LIBXML_NOCDATA`; I presumed it was required for some other parts of the XML which were not shown.

Comment: @Nick No, it's something everybody copies from each other's examples without understanding. Even if there are CDATA sections, the only difference it makes is that it reformats the *output* slightly, and makes it more likely that things show up in debug output. People mistake it for a "make CDATA work" flag, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In xml is 'zone', but in php you have 'zona'.
You not need to add the id and name attributes in array keys, just put the tag name.

```
$info = "information: ".$array['trend']['zone']['subzone']['text'];
```

Comment: Error in texting, it´s no working without the id and name tag also, there are more zone and subzone with diferent ids and names